# EggHunter not finding the egg, causing infinite loop

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

EggHunter not finding the egg (32bit), causing infinite loop
I have 1 example, that prints We found the egg! which works, and another the prints Hello egg! that isn't working.

Both use the same egg 0x90f890f9

I think the problem may be here:
cmp     dword [ecx], 0x90f890f9  ; marker

Here is the c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned char egghunter[21];

void main()
{

/* works OK (We found the egg!)

"\x90\xf9\x90\xf8\x90\x68\x21\x0a\x0a\x0a\x68\x20\x65\x67\x67\x68\x20\x74\x68"
"\x65\x68\x6f\x75\x6e\x64\x68\x57\x65\x20\x66\x31\xc9\xb1\x12\x51\xb8"
"\x11\x11\x51\x08\x50\x31\xc0\x50\x54\x51\x89\xe6\x83\xc6\x14\x03\x74"
"\x24\x10\x2b\x34\x24\x56\x89\xf1\xeb\x1c\xeb\x0c\x59\x59\xe2\xe8\x31"
"\xdb\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\xb0\xa2\x8d\x5c\x24\x0c\x31\xc9"
"\xcd\x80\xeb\xe6\x31\xd2\xb2\x01\x31\xdb\xb3\x01\x31\xc0\xb0\x04\xcd"
"\x80\xeb\xd4";

*/

/* gives an infinite loop (suppose to print Hello egg!)

"\x90\xf9\x90\xf8\x90\xeb\x17\x31\xc0\xb0\x04\x31\xdb\xb3\x01\x59\x31\xd2\xb2\x0b\xcd\x80"
"\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80\xe8\xe4\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c"
"\x6f\x20\x65\x67\x67\x21\x0a";

*/

unsigned char shellcode[256] = \
"\x90\xf9\x90\xf8\x90\xeb\x17\x31\xc0\xb0\x04\x31\xdb\xb3\x01\x59\x31\xd2\xb2\x0b\xcd\x80"
"\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80\xe8\xe4\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c"
"\x6f\x20\x65\x67\x67\x21\x0a";


printf("Shellcode: %d bytes\n", strlen(shellcode));

strcpy(egghunter,"\xeb\x0e\x59\x83\xe9\x17\x81\x39\xf9\x90\xf8\x90\xe0\xf8\xff\xe1\xe8\xed\xff\xff\xff");

printf("Egghunter: %d bytes\n", strlen(egghunter));

int (*ret)() = (int(*)())egghunter;

ret();
}
```

Here is the egghunter code:

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
  jmp     call_egghunter
egghunter:
  pop     ecx                 ; save addr ptr
  sub     ecx, 23             ; move addr ptr back
next:
  cmp     dword [ecx], 0x90f890f9  ; marker
  loopnz  next                ; dec ecx, jump
  jmp ecx                     ; jump to shellcode
call_egghunter:
  call    egghunter
```

And the hello egg code that isn't working is:
    global _start

```
section .text

_start:

    jmp short call_shellcode 


shellcode: 

    ; print hello world on the screen

    xor eax, eax
    mov al, 0x4

    xor ebx, ebx
    mov bl, 0x1

    pop ecx

    xor edx, edx
    mov dl, 11

    int 0x80


    ; exit the program gracefully

    xor eax, eax
    mov al, 0x1

    xor ebx, ebx

    int 0x80

call_shellcode:

    call shellcode
    message: db "Hello egg!", 0xA
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `egghunter` is a global variable which lives in the data section. Your `shellcode` is a local variable which lives on the stack. You search for the mark from `egghunter` downwards, however the usual layout on linux (which I assume you use due to the `int 0x80`) places the stack above the data section. As such, you are searching in the wrong direction, and whatever you are finding is not your `shellcode`. In fact, it is part of the code that does the `strcpy(egghunter, literal)`:

```
   0x80494fe:   movl   $0x90f890f9,0x80497d0
   0x8049508:   movl   $0xe1fff8e0,0x80497d4
   0x8049512:   movl   $0xffffede8,0x80497d8
   0x804951c:   movw   $0xff,0x80497dc
   0x8049525:   movl   $0x80497c8,(%esp)
```

Learn to use a debugger so you can step through the code and see what it is doing.

Comment: I'm looking at it in gdb, I'm watching ecx, but that doesn't seem to say much
What else should I be looking at in gdb?

Comment: The address of your shellcode, so you can see it is looking at the wrong place.